# The "SignName" property of class PdfPKCS7 always return null in Itext 5.5.13.2 using the C#

Tags: c#, itext, digital-signature, bouncycastle, signing

I signed the pdf successfully and also verified the pdf successfully but the "**SignName**" property of class **PdfPKCS7** **always returns null**.

I don't know why? Am I missing something during the pdf signing process or verification process?

`//res.SignName` always returns null.

`validite = "Validated : " + res.SignName;`

Pdf signing code see here: ["Invalid algorithm specified" when pdf signing with Itext 5.5.13.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74460064/invalid-algorithm-specified-when-pdf-signing-with-itext-5-5-13-2)

and Verification Code is given below.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PdfReader reader;
    reader = new PdfReader(pdfFilePath.Text);
    try
    {
        AcroFields acf = reader.AcroFields();
        List<string> sgnoms = acf.GetSignatureNames();
        List<string> sgnoms2 = acf.GetBlankSignatureNames();
        Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate cert;

        if (sgnoms.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (object obj in sgnoms)
            {
                PdfPKCS7 res = acf.VerifySignature(obj.ToString());
                string validite = "Not Validate";
                DateTime cal = res.SignDate;
                if (res.SigningCertificate.IsValid(DateTime.Now) && res.Verify())
                   //res.SignName` Always returns null          
                   validite = "Validated : " + res.SignName;
                res = null;
                validite = null;
                cal = default(DateTime);                
            }
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("Document not sign!");

        reader = null;
        acf = null;
        sgnoms = null;
        sgnoms2 = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

**Is any alternative to get the Signer Name? Or anything missing in the code?**

Please check it, Unbale to get the reason.  Am I missing something during the pdf signing process? or Am I missing something during the pdf verification process?

Any ideas, working code and suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SignName` property is the value of the **Name** entry of the signature dictionary. This entry is specified as:

| Key | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Name** | text string | *(Optional)* The name of the person or authority signing the document. This value should be used only when it is not possible to extract the name from the signature. EXAMPLE 1 From the certificate of the signer. |

*(ISO 32000-1, Table 252 – Entries in a signature dictionary)*

This entry is optional, so the value you retrieve may well be null.

There is also a hint where you can look for the signer name here: in the signer  certificate! Thus, consider inspecting the `SigningCertificate` property of your `PdfPKCS7` object.

Comment: @mki ok, trying to extract using **SigningCertificate** and get the **Signer Name**. Simply confirm if this method is the correct way you get the signer's name or not. `Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate cert;`
    `cert = res.SigningCertificate;`
   `CertificateInfo.GetSubjectFields(cert).GetField("CN");`

Comment: Actually i better know the Java variants. But conceptually that looks good. Just be prepared to look at other subject components, too, if there is no common name (`CN`) component.

Comment: @mki, Thanks for your valuable support. Going to mark it as an acceptable answer.